# React-Redux Bad Request Error (404) But Still Saves Data From Schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-redux, mongoose-schema

I'm getting a **status(400)** on a **post request** for some **nested** inventory data. **The request fulfills** by saving the data but responds with a 400. It also doesn't fulfill the **.then()** promise so I can't save the list back to the state. I have no idea why it's saving the data to MongoDB, yet it says it's a bad request.

I have a feeling the issue **stems 3 issues**:

1. The Schema **structure**,
2. The route **callbacks**,
3. The data from the component being passed in isn't **properly
   typed**.

I tried:

1. Removing the required values of the schema objects,
2. Removing the .catch() method from the route,

My data comes from a CSV file like this:

Item,ItemDescription,ItemLocation,OnHand
29081128,item1,loc1,24
29119208,item2,loc2,43
26094208,item3,loc3,4800

**Hopefully its something simple :)**

REACT COMPONENT:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Input, Button } from "reactstrap";
import { postList } from "../../../redux/inventory/inventoryActions";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
const crypto = require("crypto");

const Footer = () => {
  const inventory = useSelector((state) => state.inventory);
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };
  const onSubmit = () => {
    const list_id = crypto.randomBytes(12).toString("hex");
    const items = inventory.preparedList.map((items) => {
      const item_id = crypto.randomBytes(12).toString("hex");
      const loc_id = crypto.randomBytes(12).toString("hex");
      const loc = items.data.ItemLocation;
      const item = {
        number: items.data.Item,
        desc: items.data.ItemDescription,
        locs: [{ loc: loc, count: 0, _id: loc_id }],
        oh: parseInt(items.data.OnHand),
        _id: item_id,
      };
      return item;
    });
    const list = {
      listName: inputValue,
      _id: list_id,
      listId: auth.user.id,
      items: items,
    };
    dispatch(postList(list));
  };
  const footerContainerStyle = {
    height: "100%",
    width: "90%",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
  };
  return (
    <div style={footerContainerStyle}>
      <Button
        color="danger"
        onClick={() => {
          setInputValue("");
        }}
      >
        Reset
      </Button>
      <Input value={inputValue} onChange={onChange} placeholder="add name" />
      <Button color="success" disabled={!inputValue} onClick={onSubmit}>
        Save
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Footer;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

ACTION FILE:

```js-react-redux
import axios from "axios";

import {
  SAVE_FETCHED_LISTS,
  SAVE_POSTED_LIST,
  SAVE_PREPARED_LIST,
} from "./inventoryTypes";

export const fetchLists = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get("/inventory/lists").then((response) => {
      dispatch({
        type: SAVE_FETCHED_LISTS,
        payload: response.data,
      });
    });
  };
};

export const postList = (list) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.post("/inventory/lists", list).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.status);
      dispatch({
        type: SAVE_POSTED_LIST,
        payload: list,
      });
    });
  };
};

export const prepareList = (list) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SAVE_PREPARED_LIST,
      payload: list,
    });
  };
};
```

SCHEMA:

```js-mongoose
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const locSchema = new Schema({
  loc: { type: String, required: true },
  count: { type: Number, required: true },
  _id: { type: String, required: true },
});
mongoose.model("loc", locSchema);

const ItemSchema = new Schema({
  number: { type: String, required: true },
  desc: { type: String, required: true },
  oh: { type: Number, required: true },
  locs: [locSchema],
  _id: { type: String, required: true },
});
mongoose.model("item", ItemSchema);

const ListSchema = new Schema({
  listId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  _id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  items: [ItemSchema],
  listName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = List = mongoose.model("lists", ListSchema);
```

ROUTER:

```js-express
const router = require("express").Router();
let List = require("../models/lists");
const { authUser } = require("../middlware/auth");

router.get("/lists", (req, res) => {
  List.find()
    .then((lists) => {
      res.json(lists);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(400).json({ msg: "error: " + err });
    });
});

router.post("/lists", (req, res) => {
  const newList = new List({
    listName: req.body.listName,
    _id: req.body._id,
    listId: req.body.listId,
    items: req.body.items,
  });
  newList
    .save()
    .then((res) => res.json("list added"))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

SERVER:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const path = require("path");
const passport = require("passport");

const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(db, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

const inventoryRouter = require("./routes/inventory.js");
const usersRouter = require("./routes/users.js");

app.use(passport.initialize());
require("./config/passport")(passport);

app.use("/inventory", inventoryRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED FIXED:

ROUTE callbacks were the issue:

The res doesn't need to be passed into the then function, and the res.json needs to be in an object form for the status message.

```js
router.post("/lists", (req, res) => {
  const newList = new List({
    listName: req.body.listName,
    _id: req.body._id,
    listId: req.body.listId,
    items: req.body.items,
  });
  newList
    .save()
    .then(() => res.json({ msg: "list added" }))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```